# How can i remove this data?

Tags: r

I wanna remove part of 'city_' all of them. What kind of function should i use in RStudio?

[image: city data]

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use `gsub`

```
transform(
  df,
  city = as.numeric(gsub("city_","",city))
)
```

Comment: can this remove part of 'city_'? I want to be numeric value this attribute.

Comment: @ReiRosemary See my update. I think now it fits your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative character class that removes anything that is **not** a digit:

```
df$city <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", df$city))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `readr::parse_number` which would automatically extract numbers from the column.

```
df$city <- readr::parse_number(df$city)
```